# Any elegant way to get relative path in Python?

Tags: python

Say I want to delete `'Core.dll'` after `'git pull'`, so I write a hook.

```
import os

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
try:
    os.remove(os.path.abspath(dir+os.sep+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+"Assets"+os.sep+"Plugins"+os.sep+"Core.dll"))

except OSError:
    pass
```

Say the hook path is `'E:\client\.git\hooks'`, the file I want to delete is in `'E:\client\Assets\Plugins\Core.dll'.`

I think my way is very silly, is there any elegant way to get the relative path?

Comment: using `os.path.join` and os.pardir would be better

Comment: `/` will work as a directory separator on all platforms where you'd use both git and python... But also, on Python 3, see `pathlib`. If on Python 2 -> switch to Python 3.

Comment: also don't overload `dir`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

(Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent.parent/'Assets'/'Plugins'/'Core.dll').unlink()
```

Comment: I believe the call to `absolute()` is needed *iff* `__file__` is a relative path... because of a stupid feature in `Pathlib` that it doesn't traverse past the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Antti's solution is the best in Python 3. For Python 2, you could use `os.pardir` and `os.path.join`:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(d, os.pardir, os.pardir, "Assets", "Plugins", "Core.dll"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[os.path.relpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) would be what you asked for. You should also be using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of that long list of + and sep. In Python 3's pathlib, there's [relative_to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to). It appears your code is trying to apply a relative path, not get it in relative form. In that case, joinpath and [normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) or realpath might help.

Answer (score 0):

More readable solution:

```
import os 
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(OSError):
  dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

  while '.git' in dir:
    dir = os.path.dirname(dir)

  os.remove(
    os.path.join(
      dir,
      'Assets',
      'Plugins',
      'Core.dll'
    )
  )
```